# Dropping and recreating indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

I most often come in a situation where the users move there database from one server to another and immediately after they move they face performance problems(slowness).

I somehow manage to rebuild the indexes or reorganize them, and update the statistics, which is not much of a use.

Will dropping and recreating the indexes, and then updating the statistics, be of any help?

Comment: This question is too broad.  You need to first determine the cause for the lack of performance before making a blanket statement that index recreation and stats update will/won't help.

Comment: Agreed with @ThomasStringer. Also, when you rebuild your indexes, behind the hood it drops and recreates your indexes. There might be many other factors like memory, CPU, server settings, workload, power plan setting, etc that can contribute to poor performance. You are doing the right thing of rebuild/reorg indexes when you move database from one server to another.

Comment: Do both the servers have the same specifications/settings?

Comment: Please consider rewriting this question to make it a lot more specific.  Some info you could include to help would be sample queries/data/table structures, execution plans, server specs, etc etc etc.  As it stands this is unanswerable and it's getting closed.

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- After rebuilding indexes, do not update all statistics!
- REBUILD indexes, don't REORGANISE

An index rebuild will rebuild statistics anyway. A further update actually means you'll have worse statistics because of sampling ratio. You *can* rebuild column statistics though.

Also, it's worth comparing the server specs (RAM, CPU, Disk) and query plan XML. Does the 2nd server have different connection options that has, say, a different ARITHABORT setting?

Finally, do a comparison (say with Red Gate SQL Compare) but do ensure you compare everything: statistics, fill factors, the lot.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes fragmentation and statistics are not the only possible cause for a performance trouble.
Apart from this rebuild and reorganize are different process.

- INDEX REBUILD: it drops the existing index and recreates the index. Can be done online or offline.
- INDEX REORGANIZATION: it physically reorganizes the leaf nodes of the index. It is always online.

Which one to choose? Index should be rebuild when index fragmentation is great than 30%. Index should be reorganized when index fragmentation is between 5% to 30%. Index rebuilding process uses more CPU and it locks the database resources. ONLINE option is availabe only with SQL Server development Enterprise version. Without ONLINE clause index is simply dropped and recreated. Consider that the optimizer might change its own preference in using an index due to heavy fragmentation. It's suggested to perform regular check on index fragmentation level.

Answer (score 0):

When an index rebuilding operation is performed, it drops the index, recreates the index, and updates its statistic.

If I read the question correctly, your question of dropping indexes, recreating then update the statistics is pretty much the same as simply rebuilding the index.

Please note that index reorganization operation does not update the statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the database is used in a different way in the new location?
This is a common theme - different queries running in the database copy (perhaps reporting-style queries).

In this case you may want to drop the existing indexes and create new ones that support these new queries.

You'd first have to let them use the db on the new location for a representative amount of time, then use the indexing DMVs to find the top 'wanted' ones, then consider which ones are worth adding.

If the usage pattern is very different, you may even want to drop some clustered indexes and recreate them on more appropriate fields - it depends (as always!)